# A word which describes a representation of new technology by an older technology

Tags: single-word-requests, iconography

For instance, the app icon for email is usually an envelope. But of course the whole point of email is that one doesn't use envelopes. Similarly with the phone/call app has an icon of an older type of landline phone. I suppose this is a term used in semiotics.

Comment: You know how it's easier to learn a word in a different language if it's a cognate to one you already know? Same with pictures that are *backward compatible* -> https://www.lexico.com/definition/backwards-compatible. They are easier to recognize, and to relate to with less transition, than a new icon. I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: There is also the word *Retronym* which refers to an item that is used or named differently than it used to be. The classic is Pocket Watch; all watches were originally kept in pockets. It was when wrist watches came along that the new name for the old watch was needed as a distinction. This is not quite exact to what you need and so in only a comment.

Comment: I'm not able to find a single word that satisfies (thus only a comment), they seem to be commonly referred to as [retro icons](https://www.pngegg.com/en/png-essmm). Maybe someone will do better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, it's called *skeuomorphism*. It is a broad term and has many definitions.

> **Skeuomorphism:** A skeuomorph is physical ornament or design on an object made to resemble another material or technique. The phenomenon is called *skeuomorphism*. This definition is broader in scope, as it can be applied to design elements that still serve the same function as they did in the previous design.
>
> On a smaller scale, the icons of GUIs may remain skeuomorphic representations of physical objects that are not longer directly applicable to the task they represent.
>
> Example: a drawing of a floppy disk to represent "save".

**[[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph)**

And here's the example you've given:

> The envelope is the de-facto symbol for email and SMS messages. It offers a nice distinction between read and unread - they become opened and unopened envelopes. [[**Skeuomorphism - BBC**]](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-22840833)